# Cookie token authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, authentication, cookies

I have a MERN app, where I use passport to create/authenticate the user, and persist the auth state by storing the hashed JWT Token in a HttpOnly Secure cookie.
The only problem is that, if I log **User A in Chrome**, and copy the cookies to other browser like **Edge**, the token appears valid to the Backend, and the user appears logged in the Edge browser.

Since i'm trying to implement a csrf token, the validation should fail right?
What is the best pratices to implement this type of authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is by default. To protect against CSRF use the SameSite=lax cookie attribute and\or anti-CSRF tokens